# C# How to use properties

Tags: c#

A simple program using properties to encapsulate.. Farmer has field `snumberofCows` and`feedMultiplier`,
and write to console `BagsOfFeed= numberofCows* feedMultiplier`

```
namespace numberOfCows
{
    class Farmer
    {
        private int bagsOfFeed;
        //public const int FeedMultiplier = 30;
        private int numberOfCows;
        private int feedMultiplier;
        //private int bagsOfFeed;
        public Farmer(int numberOfCows, int feedMultiplie)
        {
            feedMultiplier = feedMultiplie;
            //this.feedMultiplier = feedMultiplie;
            NumberOfCows = numberOfCows;
            //this.numberOfCows = numberOfCows;
        }
        public int FeedMultiplier { get { return feedMultiplier; } }
        public int NumberOfCows
        {
            get
            {
                return numberOfCows;
            }
            set
            {
                numberOfCows = value;
                //BagsOfFeed = numberOfCows * FeedMultiplier;
            }
        }
        //READ ONLY PROPERTY
        public int BagsOfFeed {
            get { return bagsOfFeed; }
            set { bagsOfFeed = NumberOfCows * FeedMultiplier; }
        }
    }
}
```

When call `farmer = new Farmer( 15,30 ); Console.WriteLine("I need {0} bags of feed for {1} cows",farmer.BagsOfFeed, farmer.NumberOfCows);` returns 0 `BagsOfFeed`...So I don't know where i goes wrong..[I thought properties is used to retrieve values which is to read sth out...also,,when should i use private set..]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `set` method for `BagsOfFeed` is never called since you never do `BagsOfFeed = something;`, so the calculation is never done. You should probably have the calculation in the `get` method, and remove the field for it. Your class also has other fields that don't need to exist. For example, with the `FeedMultiplier` property, you can use `private set;` (this is called an [auto-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)) instead of having just a `get` with a backing field. It could be rewritten as:

```
class Farmer
{
    public Farmer(int numberOfCows, int feedMultiplier)
    {
        this.FeedMultiplier = feedMultiplier;
        this.NumberOfCows = numberOfCows;
    }
    public int FeedMultiplier { get; private set; }
    public int NumberOfCows { get; set; }
    public int BagsOfFeed {
        get { return NumberOfCows * FeedMultiplier; }
    }
}
```

This shows the correct result in your example:

> I need 450 bags of feed for 15 cows

Comment: Ok. One more question. If I used `private set`, does that mean i can't call `farmer.FeedMultiplier= sth` from any created instance?

Comment: `private set` means, you can only assign values to that property from within the class.

Answer (score 4):

`BagsOfFeed` setter is never called (and shouldn't be, as it's calculated based of values of other properties). This property should look like that:

```
    //READ ONLY PROPERTY
    public int BagsOfFeed {
        get { return NumberOfCows * FeedMultiplier; }
    }
```

With that, `private int bagsOfFeed;` can be removed as it's unnecessary.

Comment: +1. @XunBao - it is property... possibly you use some other meaning of "property" that does not align with C# (maybe "field"?).